# What is the correctt way to check headers with file_get_contents

Tags: php, http-headers

What is the correct/best way to check headers with the file_get_contents function? For example this is the code I'm using right now based on RIOT's API for league of legends stats:

```
$summonerName = htmlspecialchars($_POST["main_summoner"]);
$url = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $summonerName . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
$result = json_decode($url, true);
$summoner = $result[$summonerName]['name'];
```

I know how to turn the headers into a array using

```
$http_response_header
```

But what is the correct way to find extract the first header and check its value?
Do I compare the first value in the array to a 404 error for instance or do I need to check if the string contains a keyword? What is the correct way to go about this?

EDIT
Here is my new/working code

```
$url1 = "https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" . $summonerName . "?api_key=" . $apiKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url1);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

And I check the httpcode with:

```
if($httpCode !== 404) {
```

Comment: You should be getting everything you need in the $http_response_header, if you need to check for 200 or 404 Status code use something like if(strpos($http_response_header[0],'200 OK') !== false){....}.

There is not much more you can do with file_get_contents()...

Comment: @PavelPetrov Thanks, I was just wondering what the best way was to check what the headers containt. All I could find was people telling me to use $http_response_header but no one seemed to elaborate on it

Comment: Why not use curl and then `curl_getinfo` and then check array for `http_code`? Or use the suggested header formatter in the comment at : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php#117203

Comment: You will definately have more control with curl. 
http://codular.com/curl-with-php
And after a request goes through (or doesn't) you do curl_getinfo ( resource $ch [, int $opt = 0 ] ) and get the last HTTP code returned

Comment: @Anthony damn it! Beat me to it :D ...

Comment: +1 for asking the question. I didn't even realize that remotely fetched file content retained the headers. Could be good for low level http client when curl isn't possible

Comment: @pavel - we were all thinking it. Just glad our combined comments offsets the "duhh, you're doing it all wrong. Snfff" vibe I was afraid might come across.

Comment: Thanks everyone :p If someone could post it as a real answer Ill mark it